# How to convert result_array() to result() object in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need JSON output like this,

```
{"restaurant":[{"id":"89","owner_id":"2161","name":"Bakso ",...}{"id":"90","owner_id":"3400","name":"Soto"}]}
```

And I do using this query and work perfectly:

```
$latest_rest = $this->Restaurants_model->getLatestRestaurants($limit)->result();
$jsonObject = array('restaurant'=>$latest_rest);
```

but i have query with `result_array()`, because I must filtering this data through function that return `result_array();`

how do I convert `result_array()` to `result()` in CodeIgniter?

Comment: if you want response in object then return $query->result(); only

Comment: Why don't you just call `result()` instead of `result_array()`?  Also, if you are just encoding it as JSON anyway, why does it matter if you use `result()` or `result_array()`?  What problem are you trying to solve here exactly?  What output are you getting compared to the output you want?

Comment: I was solved the problem, result() or result_array(), json outputs are same like above,

Answer (score 3):

If it is mandatory to get result in array in beginning then to get json data you can first encode data into json and later can decode as:

```
$object = json_decode(json_encode($array));
```

And, if it is not necessary in beginning then you can get result in object directly as:

```
$this->db->select('*')->from..........;
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result(); // instead of result_array();
```